# MySQL MIN() and MAX() with LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to fetch a MIN() and MAX() value from a query so that I can use the resulting values in a PHP function but can't seem to work out how to do it because there is a LIMIT involved.

```
SELECT MIN(ID) AS MinID, MAX(ID) AS MaxID 
FROM parts_listing 
WHERE BaseGroup = 0
LIMIT 0,50;
```

This is a dynamically-generated LIMIT used by a pagination function so in this example, should give MinID = 1 and MAXID = 50 but instead gives MinID = 1 and MinID = 129, which is the number of total records in BaseGroup 0. If I use any of the other BaseGroup values, it also gives the total values. If I change the starting record of LIMIT to, for example, LIMIT 10,50 I get nothing whatsoever.

I realized that there are similar questions here but they did not help in this specific case. Any ideas?

Comment: I think the problem if you are in a PHP environment is with the order of the numbers; you could use LIMIT 0 OFFSET 50 or the short syntax LIMIT 50,0 (the numbers in this one must be reverted)

Answer (score 7):

`LIMIT` is applied **after** processing the `MIN`/`MAX`, when there's only a single row left.

You need to move it to a Derived Table:

```
SELECT MIN(ID) AS MinID, MAX(ID) AS MaxID 
FROM
 (
   SELECT ID 
   FROM parts_listing 
   WHERE BaseGroup = 0
   LIMIT 0,50
 ) as dt
```

And you probably need an `ORDER BY`, too.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I had tried every possible way of doing it and even tried a derived table but never got a result but seeing your example, I was using WHERE ID IN rather than as a FROM. Makes sense and works! (Yes, the actual query has an ORDER BY.)

Comment: As a follow up, it is all working now and probably well enough for my needs but it's giving odd results. For example, with ORDER BY GroupNumber and LIMIT 10,50 it gives MinID = 9 and MaxID = 61 which is 52 entries and without the ORDER BY it gives MinID = 11 and MaxID = 60 which is 49 entries. Without ORDER BY and with LIMIT 0,50 it gives MinID = 1 and MaxID = 61 as it should, which is 50 entries.

Comment: @DonP: Is the GroupNumber unique? Without ORDER BY it's based on the physical order within the table, currently working correct, but there's no guarantee it will work the same when there ara updates/deletes...

Answer (score 2):

LIMIT does not limit how record are using mysql to calculate MIN or MAX functions. ALL RECORDS that matches WHERE criteria are used to calculate results

In other word LIMIT has no any sense with aggregate functions

LIMIT does not see query, just see result set, if query outputs more than one row, limits works with that

You need to use WHERE clausule, to "limit" rows used in aggregate functions